# Python Class Printing Information Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I tried to create a basic class example by myself. However, I get an error from line 51 that I mentioned by #ERROR next to the code.

Error information given below. Also, if I try to get info by show_info from worker class, there is no error on program. I couldn't understand the reason of that situation.

Can you help me about how to solve the problem. Thank you to all
I'm beginner for coding.

```
class worker():

    def __init__(self, name, salary, department):
        print("__init__ function of worker class.")
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.department = department

    def show_info_worker(self):
        print("show_info function of worker class")
        print("""Name: {}\nSalary: {}\nDepartment: {}""".format(self.name, self.salary, self.department))

    def change_depart(self, new_depart):
        print("change_depart function of worker class")
        self.department = new_depart



class manager(worker):

    def __init__(self, name, salary, department, responsibilty):
        # super() function takes input from worker class
        super().__init__(name, salary, department)
        print("__init function of manager class")
        self.responsibilty = responsibilty

    def show_info_manager(self):
        print("show_info function of manager class")
        return """Name: {}\nSalary: {}\nDepartment: {}\nResponsibility: {}""".format(self.name, self.salary,
                                                                                    self.department,
                                                                                    self.responsibilty)

    def raise_salary(self, increase_salary):
        print("raise_salary function of manager class")
        self.salary += increase_salary


employee_name = input("Please Enter Employee Name: ")
employee_salary = input("Please Enter Employee Salary: ")
employee_department = input("Please Enter Employee Department: ")
while True:
    check_manager = int(input("""Please Select the Position of Employee\n1. Worker\n2. Manager"""))
    if check_manager == 1:
        worker1 = worker(employee_name, employee_salary, employee_department)
        worker1.show_info_worker()
        break
    elif check_manager == 2:
        manager_responsibility = input("Please Enter Manager Responsibility: ")
        manager1 = manager(employee_name, employee_salary, employee_department, manager_responsibility)
        manager1 = manager.show_info_manager()  # <-- ERROR!!!
        break
    else:
        print("Please Enter a Proper Value...")
```

Error is given below.

```
manager1 = manager.show_info_manager()
TypeError: show_info_manager() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Hint: follow [the naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use CamelCase for your class names. This helps avoiding this kind of issues ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up something in your code which I corrected. 
You were trying to call the `show_info_manager()` on `manager1` instance in the wrong way.

```
class worker():

    def __init__(self, name, salary, department):
        print("__init__ function of worker class.")
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.department = department

    def show_info_worker(self):
        print("show_info function of worker class")
        print("""Name: {}\nSalary: {}\nDepartment: {}""".format(self.name, self.salary, self.department))

    def change_depart(self, new_depart):
        print("change_depart function of worker class")
        self.department = new_depart



class manager(worker):

    def __init__(self, name, salary, department, responsibilty):
        # super() function takes input from worker class
        super().__init__(name, salary, department)
        print("__init function of manager class")
        self.responsibilty = responsibilty

    def show_info_manager(self):
        print("show_info function of manager class")
        return """Name: {}\nSalary: {}\nDepartment: {}\nResponsibility: {}""".format(self.name, self.salary,
                                                                                    self.department,
                                                                                    self.responsibilty)

    def raise_salary(self, increase_salary):
        print("raise_salary function of manager class")
        self.salary += increase_salary


employee_name = input("Please Enter Employee Name: ")
employee_salary = input("Please Enter Employee Salary: ")
employee_department = input("Please Enter Employee Department: ")
while True:
    check_manager = int(input("""Please Select the Position of Employee\n1. Worker\n2. Manager"""))
    if check_manager == 1:
        worker1 = worker(employee_name, employee_salary, employee_department)
        worker1.show_info_worker()
        break
    elif check_manager == 2:
        manager_responsibility = input("Please Enter Manager Responsibility: ")
        manager1 = manager(employee_name, employee_salary, employee_department, manager_responsibility)
        manager1.show_info_manager()  # Corrected
        break
    else:
        print("Please Enter a Proper Value...")
```